# create file with ffmpeg by for?

Tags: loops, ffmpeg

I want

```
for %i in("%image%\*.jpg")for %%i in ("%INPUT%\*.mp3") DO ffmpeg -i %%i -i %i -filter_complex "scale=1280:720[v]" -map '[v]' -map '[a]'  -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -preset superfast "%OUTPUT%/%%~ni.mp4"
```

but it not run.